# Underscore.js template on Java server

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm building a single page web app when [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) is my MV* framework. It requires [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) so I wan't to use it as my template engine.
I set the template result as the view content to display in it's ***render*** function:

```
this.el.append( compiledTemplate );
```

I wonder about the right way to implement the template code:

1. Should it be a JS code that produce an HTML text?
2. Should it be an HTML file with a script tag to include the JS code?
3. How can I separate the display from the logic?
4. How can I write my CSS in a separate file (not in JS file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Well... this is what the Underscore template engine is, isn't it? so, no, your template should be HTML with *interpolate* tags.
2. Normally it is a DOM element whose content is the template, and, yes, it is used to be a `script` tag.
3. Force your self to only use *interpolate* Model attributes in your templates. You can pass especial pre-calculated attributes if you use any kind of *Decorator* technique.
4. There is not any Backbone or Underscore restriction to you not include your external CSS files as usual.